# I want to type <enter> in expanded combo box, and it should set empty value

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

Repro steps:

1. Go to http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/form/xml-form.html
2. Click on trigger on State combo box field.
3. Type enter key.

Expected result: Value should remain empty.

Actual result: Selects first item in list (Alabama)

How do I accomplish my expected result? Note that in my own application, I am using a time field, so I am not specifying my own list of items such that I could add an empty value. That is, unless there's an easy way to do this in the time field.

Comment: i don't understand the problem. when i visit the link and press the spacebar after clicking on the trigger, it remains empty.

Comment: Not really. The value is ' ' (i.e., blank space). And in any event, I'm also trying to make it as user-friendly as possible. My users don't think like engineers. (Also note that my original post did not display properly because I used html-style carrots. I wrote that if you type the "enter" key, it does not remain blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

```
autoSelect: false
```

to your select field. And then the first Item will not be selected.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much Darin. I'm not sure why someone else down-voted my question, but clearly it was a valid question so much so that Sencha added a special config property for it.